# Windows 8 Single Language

Tags: windows, windows-8, language

I have a Windows 8 Single Language, then under System, I used the "Get more features with new edition of Windows" then entered the product key of Windows 8 Pro that I got from Dreamspark.

Now, I open App Store then try to update to Windows 8.1 then it say's "Windows 8.1 Single Language Pack" not Windows 8.1 Pro or something so there is an error saying "Your Windows 8.1 install couldn't be completed. Something happened and the install of Windows 8.1 can't be completed."

Is there anyway to revert back to Windows 8 Single Language Pack and Update to Windows 8.1 Single Language pack ?

By the way, when I was in my Win 8 Single Language and tried updating to Win 8.1, it downloaded and I cancelled it because it's not Win 8.1 Pro.

Comment: The reason you can't update to 8.1 isn't because your system isn't Windows 8 Professional it's likwly because of a language region difference between the key you used

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The product key activated at present is that of Pro (dreamspark).  When you try to update, the system checked your present version (8.1 SL) and not the product key (dreamspark).

So, remove the Pro product key.  This can be done by replacing the present key (Pro) with your original key (SL).

Once you do that, your system and product key, both are for SL. Update to 8.1 using that.  Then, apply your PRO key.

Comment: It says that "The product key you have entered will not work with this edition of Windows 8. You must either run Windows 8 Setup or enter a Windows 8 Pro product key."

Comment: and after I used the "Get more features with new edition of Windows" my Operating System became windows 8 pro.

Comment: No; it didn't because of it did; it would report it as being Windows 8 Professional; the only upgrade that exists for Single Language is actually the Pro Pack which includes Media Center; I shocked it accepted your profesional key honestly

Comment: @Ramhound Appreciate your help.  I had overlooked Dustin's comments.

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution;  But its technically correct;  It was also on the first page for me.  I wanted to reward a technically correct answer with an upvote.